# Ajax post returns empty array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a very simple php page with a jquery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                myvar: 1,
            },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log("it works");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My AJAX function is supposed to be triggered as soon as the document is ready. My test.php just shows my `$_POST`.

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    die();
```

Nothing is happening. I should go to test.php and see the var_dump. It works if I have a button and start the AJAX function on the click but not like that... Isn't possible to do so ?

Comment: What's the specific problem you're observing?  What does the `result` variable in your AJAX success handler contain?  (I don't see where your code is even observing that value...)  In your browser's debugging tools, what specifically is returned from the server?

Comment: it should work that way

Comment: are you viewing this result in network tab in your devtools?

Comment: @mplungjan i also see that comma, but i think its okay since it is still an object, not a json string.

Comment: Yeah yeah! You too @RokoC.Buljan ;)

Comment: @David My main problem is that `var_dump($_POST)` returns an empty array where I expected to see myvar in it. 
The `result` variable in my AJAX success handler is an array (I expect to receive the array $result written in my subsidiary question)

Comment: @Thbwun: Where/how specifically are you observing this result?  (The code never references `result`, but just logs a literal string to the console.)  I'm not able to replicate the results described with the code shown.

Comment: Yeah, i also waiting, where are you seeing this `array(0) { }`

Comment: @JovylleBermudez In my test.php (the url in the AJAX function) I just have a `var_dump($_POST)`; and a `die();` That is where I see the `array(0) {} `

Comment: yes, let me just give a image.

Comment: @David If I delete `die();` I have some code executed (a PDF is created among other things) including the creation of an array that I need to be able to use in my success function.

Comment: @Thbwun: Please be more specific when you indicate "that is where I see...".  Currently the code shown *ignores the response data*.  Are you seeing your string logged to the console when the AJAX operation completes?  Are you looking at the result in the browser's script debugger?  In the browser's network requests log?  Somewhere else?  It's entirely possible that you're making a mistake somewhere, and we can't rule that out if you won't provide information about the problem.

Comment: https://zerobacklog.com/swiftytools/uploads/pile_2020/2020-06-23_14:11:33_image.png

please see the link below please. is it from there you are observing it? Or you are accessing it directly like this https://zerobacklog.com/swiftytools/uploads/pile_2020/2020-06-23_14:14:30_image.png

Comment: @JovylleBermudez My mistake ! The question was badly asked due to the numerous tests I have made. I will edit it ! Sorry

Comment: @Thbwun: Regarding the updated question... "Nothing is happening" is a bit of a non-starter.  *Something* happens, it's just a matter of observing what.  Are there any errors or warnings at all on the browser's development console?  In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  If so, what is the server's response?  If not, using the browser's script debugger, place a breakpoint on the first line of JavaScript code and reload the page, is that code executed at all?  Add an `error` callback to `$.ajax()`, is that callback invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Since on the Back-end part you expect `$_POST` the best you can do is to use

[FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // Your object
  const data = {
    myvar: 1,
    foo: "foo",
  };

  // Create FormData from Object
  const FD = new FormData();
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([prop, val]) => FD.append(prop, val));


  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false, // https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
    data: FD, // pass the formData and enjoy with $_POST in PHP
    success: function(result) {
      console.log("it works", result);
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

I test your code work with datatype like :

ajax page:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json', //add that line
            data: {
                myvar: 1,
            },
            success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
                console.log(result['name']);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: *"dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))*" Source:   https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i don't understand, if you don't use datatype don't work.

Comment: Why do you think it will not work? jQuery as soon as it sees `{` as the `data` value *will* treat it as JSON

Comment: i might suspect, that Tbhwun is not viewing it on networks tab on devtools

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan 
I thought that the problem was the output, in fact, taking the given code by those who asked the question testing it locally does not work, instead using the datatype it all works.

Comment: @Simone well, See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62536510/383904

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I added dataType: 'json' but `var_dump($_POST)' still shows an empty array

Comment: @SimoneRossaini there's a huge difference in sending JSON and using `$_POST` instead of `input::` - To recap. You need to submit a `<form>` or JS's `FormData` otherwise you need to parse the `input::` String into a PHP Array Object - Or even using JS's serialization libraries like jQuery's `.serialize()` .. .or even Stringify.... etc etc

Comment: To confirm: `dataType` is used on the *result* - the return value from the ajax call ie `success:function(result) { _here_ }`.  It has no impact on the `contentType` which would be used by the test.php (server-side).